# flutter: send Authorization Token along http header

Tags: flutter, http

I am making a request in postman with the same URL that i use in my UI code and in the header passing accept and Authorization with bearer token. In postman it is working completely fine and giving desired response but in flutter in my code the token not send to server when i print my header using `print(response.headers)` it print `{x-powered-by: Express, connection: keep-alive, keep-alive: timeout=5, date: Thu, 30 Sep 2021 16:47:57 GMT, content-length: 429, etag: W/"1ad-Nsvj6qTf+5iQsO/n7VuLkLMax/M", content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8}` that means the Authorization part not send along the request header how can i send the authorization and token along to http post request ? please guide me it take my long hours but still not working.
here is my code:

```
var token='somethings';
response = await http.post(uri,
        headers: {
          
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(account[i]));
```

Comment: Authorization data will not be present in the response header, it is added to the request header. Does your post request work?

Comment: no it not work it not send the token

Comment: Can you try another request that does not need authorization? It could be some networking issue. What is in your `uri`? Is it https or http?

Comment: thank you so match, actually the problem was with my API . i when i print the header but not see the token thought me be my http request have some problem your answer change my mind and finally fined the error @PeterKoltai

Answer (score 1):

```
headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic your_api_token_here',
  },
```